# How can i do a RPN calculation in a stack?

Tags: c, stack

The question from a C programming book i am trying to solve is this and i am having a hard time understanding especially how pop() function works in this case:

> For example, 1 + 2 would be written 1 2 + in RPN, and 1 + 2 * 3 would be written 1 2 3 * +. RPN expressions can easily be evaluated using a stack. The algorithm involves reading the operators and operands in an expression from left to right, performing the following actions:
>
> When an operand is encountered, push it onto the stack.
>
> When an operator is encountered, pop its operands from the stack, perform the operation on those operands and then push the result onto the stack.
>
> Write a program that evaluates RPN expressions. The operands will be single-digit integers, The operators are +, -, *, /, and =. 
>   The = operator causes the top stack item to be displayed; afterwards, the stack is cleared and the user is prompted to enter another expression. The process continues until the user enters a character that is not an operator or operand:
>
> Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 * + =
>
> Value of expression: 7
>
> Enter an RPN expression: 5 8 * 4 9 - / =
>
> Value of expression: -8
>
> Enter an RPN expression: q
>
> If the stack overflows, the program will display the message Expression is too complex and terminate. If the stack underflows (because of an expression such as 1 2 + +), the program will display the message Not enough operands in expression and terminate. Hints: Incorporate the stack code from Section 10.2 into your program. Use scanf(" %c", &ch) to read the operators and operands.

```
case '+':   push(pop() + pop());
                    break;

case '-':   operand2 = pop();
            operand1 = pop();
            push(operand1 - operand2);
            break;

case '*':   push(pop() * pop());
            break;

case '/':   operand2 = pop();
            operand1 = pop();
            push(operand1 / operand2);
            break;
```

These are examples i can't understand how pop() knows which number to chose.

Answer (score 0):

> These are examples i can't understand how pop() knows which number to chose.

A stack has an area to store items and a variable to keep track of the current "top of stack". For example:

```
int myStack[1000];        // Area to store items
int myStackTop = 1000;    // Current "top of stack"
```

For popping it might look like:

```
int pop(void) {
    int value = 0;

    if(myStackTop > 1000) {
        // Stack is empty, can't pop!
    } else {
        value = myStack[myStackTop];
        myStackTop++;
    }
    return value;
}
```

For pushing it might be like:

```
void pop(int value) {

    if(myStackTop <= 0) {
        // Stack is full, can't push!
    } else {
        myStackTop--;
        myStack[myStackTop] = value;
    }
}
```

Mostly; it's that "current top of stack" variable that keeps track of which number will be chosen.